# Why softKeyboardBehavior PAN is not working?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

So, I've made an AIR app and put in my manifest

```
`<softKeyboardBehavior>pan</softKeyboardBehavior>`
```

I've also put my app into "CPU" mode (and tried "auto" too).
But when I click on a textfield, the keyboard is covering it.

Should I do something else in my code to make the app goes up when clicking on a textfield ?

Answer (score 0):

`android:windowSoftInputMode` is used to push the content up when an input appears below the keyboard

try use these codes in your android manfiset:

```
 <application>
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">  or use "adjustPan"
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that AIR app got a different xml manifest file. I don't know where to put         
       '<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>'

Comment: Ok, it seems that AIR doesn't allow android:windowSoftInputMode in manifest... https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffe.html application element
You cannot set the following attributes of the application element:

android:theme

android:name

android:label

android:windowSoftInputMode

Comment: ok, I see an example on the distriqt website and tell you my answer https://docs.airnativeextensions.com/docs/nativewebview/add-the-extension